# Why doesn't Bazel hash the JDK version used by build tools as part of cache key

Tags: bazel

I can see in the documentation there is `--javabase` [flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--javabase) that allows you to reference a specific jdk binary installation.
But why isn't there a way to just specify a JDK version as part of the hash key and allow any jdk installation which is marked with that version be used?

After all the moto of java is `write once run anywhere`.

Answer (score -1):

In the past, the JAVA_HOME directory was hardcoded, and this option was added looong ago to support different JDKs.

I'm not sure why it was done this way, but there must be a way to reference an exact JDK, even if it's not in the path, and we also need to distinguish different vendors 
(eg openjdk or Oracle).